# Create pypi package for fork of non-maintained project

Tags: python, pypi

I found a major problem in a nice pypi-package. I forked it on github and fixed the bug.

Problem: The project seems to be not maintained anymore and the author is not replying to my pull request.

I want to put the project to pypi but then some questions occurred to me:

1. You have to write the author and source url of the project. How do I deal with this? I'm not the author, just from the changes. I don't want to take away credit from the original guy.
2. The fork has old tags/version numbers. How to I start at version 1.0.0 again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after talking to some really experienced guys, this is what they'd do:

1. Try reach maintainers via github
2. Try to find out their email address (maybe via git-commit) and ask what's going on
3. If they don't want to maintain it anymore, ask for maintainership
4. If you don't get any reply, the last and not nice solution would be that you create a new package and start on top of the versioning of the original package. Meaning the current state is at `1.10.4` and you fix a bug, your new packages first version would be `1.10.5`